# does PHP's time() always round down to the second?

Tags: php

Does PHP's time() function round to the nearest second, or round down to the second?

For example, if the time is 11:25:31.9, would time() return the second as 31 (rounded down) or as 32 (rounded to nearest second)?

Comment: I don't think the system counts seconds with such accuracy.

Comment: "microtime() returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds. This function is only available on operating systems that support the gettimeofday() system call." From the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP [`time()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) so it will count only seconds and centiseconds won't be considered at all.

If you want a more precision timestamp use [`microtime()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) that returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds. But remember that this function is only available on operating systems that support the gettimeofday() system call.

Check this [DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_microtime).